# Is this call to `device_show_int()` a Linux kernel bug?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I started by asking this question: [How do I initialize the attribute group correctly for a platform driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24618284/32836)

And came to the conclusion that function calling `device_show_int()` was doing so with the wrong function prototype.

The code problem starts by defining the  `struct dev_ext_attribute` structure using the `DEVICE_INT_ATTR()` macro.  The `[struct device_attribute][1]` structure has the `show` field defined as pointer to a function taking three (3) arguments:

```
struct device_attribute {
    struct attribute        attr;
    ssize_t (*show)(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr,
                    char *buf);
    ssize_t (*store)(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr,
                     const char *buf, size_t count);
};
```

Yet in my call stack (please the question referenced above) the dereferenced function is being called with only two (2) arguments from [drv_attr_show()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/base/bus.c#L54):

```
if (drv_attr->show)
        ret = drv_attr->show(drv_priv->driver, buf);
```

**This seems pretty egregious, is it a bug or have I somehow managed to screw up the kernel build?** (ARM, Kernel 3.12)

Comment: What's the value of `drv_attr->show`? :-) C isn't typesafe (especially not hardcore kernel C), so you cannot argue about correctness based on types. Correctness depends on *values*.

Comment: @KerrekSB But the *value* doesn't tell the compiler how to format the call stack, the *type* or *cast* does.  Somehow, since no errors are thrown in compiling the kernel, I'm guessing I've mixed my types up somehow because the between defining the structure and invoking the function pointer, the `show` field goes from 3 to 2 arguments.  Nonetheless, to answer your question,  `drv_attr->show` = `device_show_int`: a function with three (3) parameters (see: callstack from other question).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing `device_attribute` and `driver_attribute`. The function `drv_attr_show()` works on a `struct driver_attribute`, which is defined as:

```
struct driver_attribute {
    struct attribute attr;
    ssize_t (*show)(struct device_driver *driver, char *buf);
    ssize_t (*store)(struct device_driver *driver, const char *buf,
                     size_t count);
};
```

So no bug here.

Comment: You're right, I was confusing it. Documented as such in the other question.