# How to attach file operations to sysfs attribute in platform driver?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, sysfs

I wrote a platform driver for a peripheral we developed and would like to expose some configuration options to the sysfs. I have managed to create the appropriate files using attribute structs (see below) and `sysfs_create_file` in the probe function, but I can't figure out how to attach the show/store functions to the structs in a platform driver.

Most resources I found online used a `device_attribute` struct or something similar to create their files, is that also appropriate here? Is there another way to do this for a platform driver?

My attribute struct looks like this:

```c
struct attribute subkey_attr = {
    .name = "subkeys",
    .mode = S_IWUGO | S_IRUGO,
};
```

And I register the file using this call:

```c
riddler_kobject = &pdev->dev.kobj;
ret_val = sysfs_create_file(riddler_kobject, &subkey_attr);
```

Comment: What kernel version you are using? API for creating sysfs files had a major change at some point, so you can find different ways how to create those files out there.

Comment: I'm using kernel 4.1

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It boils down to next:

- reuse existing kobject from `struct device` (from your `struct platform_device`) for `sysfs_create_group()` (instead of creating your own `kobject`)
- use `DEVICE_ATTR()` to declare `struct device_attribute` instead of regular `__ATTR()`, which creates `struct kobj_attribute`.

Here is how I created sysfs attributes for my platform driver.

1. Create structure you'll be using as private data in `show()` / `store()` operations for your sysfs attribute (file). For example:

   ```c
   struct mydrv {
       struct device *dev;
       long myparam;
   };
   ```
2. Allocate this structure in your driver's `probe()`:

   ```c
   static int mydrv_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
   {
       struct mydrv *mydrv;

       mydrv = devm_kzalloc(&pdev->dev, sizeof(*mydrv), GFP_KERNEL);
       mydrv->dev = &pdev->dev;
       platform_set_drvdata(pdev, mydrv);

       ...
   }
   ```
3. Create `show()` / `store()` functions:

   ```c
   static ssize_t mydrv_myparam_show(struct device *dev,
           struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf)
   {
       struct mydrv *mydrv = dev_get_drvdata(dev);
       int len;

       len = sprintf(buf, "%d\n", mydrv->myparam);
       if (len <= 0)
           dev_err(dev, "mydrv: Invalid sprintf len: %d\n", len);

       return len;
   }

   static ssize_t mydrv_myparam_store(struct device *dev,
           struct device_attribute *attr, const char *buf, size_t count)
   {
       struct mydrv *mydrv = dev_get_drvdata(dev);

       kstrtol(buf, 10, &mydrv->myparam);
       return count;
   }
   ```
4. Create device attribute for those functions (right after those functions):

   ```c
   static DEVICE_ATTR(myparam, S_IRUGO | S_IWUSR, mydrv_myparam_show,
                      mydrv_myparam_store);
   ```
5. Declare attributes table (listing in fact **sysfs files** for you driver):

   ```c
   static struct attribute *mydrv_attrs[] = {
       &dev_attr_myparam.attr,
       NULL
   };
   ```
6. Declare attribute group (specifying in fact **sysfs directory** for your driver):

   ```c
   static struct attribute_group mydrv_group = {
       .name = "mydrv",
       .attrs = mydrv_attrs,
   };

   static struct attribute_group *mydrv_groups[] = {
       &mydrv_group,
       NULL
   }
   ```

   which can be actually replaced with one line:

   ```c
   ATTRIBUTE_GROUPS(mydrv);
   ```
7. Create sysfs directory and files in your driver's `probe()` function:

   ```c
   static int mydrv_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
   {
       int ret;

       ...

       ret = sysfs_create_group(&pdev->dev.kobj, &mydrv_group);
       if (ret) {
           dev_err(&pdev->dev, "sysfs creation failed\n");
           return ret;
       }

       ...
   }
   ```
8. Remove your sysfs files in your driver's `remove()` function:

   ```c
   static int mydrv_remove(struct platform_device *pdev)
   {
       sysfs_remove_group(&pdev->dev.kobj, &mydrv_group);
       ...
   }
   ```

### Race condition note

As @FranzForstmayr correctly pointed out, there may be **race condition** when adding sysfs files with `sysfs_create_group()` in `mydrv_probe()`. That's because user-space can be already notified that those files exist before `mydrv_probe()` called (where those files are actually being created by `sysfs_create_group()` function). This issue covered in details in ["How to Create a sysfs File Correctly"](http://kroah.com/log/blog/2013/06/26/how-to-create-a-sysfs-file-correctly/) article by Greg Kroah-Hartman.

So in our case of `platform_device`, instead of calling `sysfs_create_group()` (and its counterpart `sysfs_remove_group()`), you can use **default attribute group**. To do so, you need to assign corresponding `.groups` field of your `struct device` to your attribute groups variable:

```c
static int mydrv_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
    ...

    pdev->dev.groups = mydrv_groups;

    ...
}
```

**DISCLAIMER**: I didn't test this code, though it should work, because of [this](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=57c745340a60c51d2b9af3d4dcf7e0ede284855b) code.

See [1,2,3] links for more insights on mentioned race condition.

For more examples, run next command in kernel source directory:

```
$ git grep -l --all-match -e platform_device -e attribute -e '\.groups =' -- drivers/
```

Also you can search by "default attribute" in commit messages:

```
$ git log --no-merges --oneline --grep="default attribute" -- drivers/
```

Some commits I found this way: [4,5,6,7].

### References

[1] [My attributes are way too racy, what should I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38620723/my-attributes-are-way-too-racy-what-should-i-do)

[2] [PATCH: sysfs: add devm_sysfs_create_group() and friends](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/7526551/)

[3] [[GIT PATCH] Driver core patches for 3.11-rc2](https://lkml.org/lkml/2013/7/18/438)

[4] [commit 1](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=266dcff03eed0050b6af11aaf2a61ab837d7ba3f)

[5] [commit 2](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=2dc10f8963e6a03a1a75deafe1d1984bafab08dd)

[6] [commit 3](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=9d3ab801740ab5ff1e22932fdfecdaacd0d64a18)

[7] [commit 4](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=5b187b3c0edf9aae6ebbad61b9fbb4ec1795e18b)

Comment: Can you explain how to adapt this solution according to the post of Greg KH? http://kroah.com/log/blog/2013/06/26/how-to-create-a-sysfs-file-correctly/

Comment: @FranzForstmayr That's a valid point. Frankly I didn't know about that. But I added **Race condition note** to my answer, explaining how to use insights from article you mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

Not enough reputation to post a comment, but I just want to comment on the **default attribute group** note from the accepted answer.
My understanding is that this should not be added in the probe function, as given in the example, but instead should be set in the device struct, (or device_driver, class, or bus depending on your driver)  usually defined at the end of your file.
For example:

```
static struct device iio_evgen_dev = {
    .bus = &iio_bus_type,
    .groups = iio_evgen_groups,
    .release = &iio_evgen_release,
};
```

from [this](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1b39eacdbdff16bae0e2ca56b3b2a3c1b4b08143/drivers/iio/dummy/iio_dummy_evgen.c) example

Strangely, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618284/how-do-i-initialize-the-attribute-group-correctly-for-a-platform-driver) it doesn't work correctly when using `DEVICE_INT_ATTR` to create the attribute, so not sure what that's all about.

Also, I'm not 100% sure, but I think that [this](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=57c745340a60c51d2b9af3d4dcf7e0ede284855b) is invoked when the driver is loaded, not when the device is probed.

Answer (score 4):

**This is an addition to Sam Protsenko's and Anthony's answers**

If you create **device** attributes via the `DEVICE_ATTR` macros then you have to register the attribute groups (`mydrv_groups`) in the `.dev_groups` instead of the `.groups` field.

```
static struct device_driver iio_evgen_dev = {
    .bus = &iio_bus_type,
    .dev_groups = iio_evgen_groups, // .dev_groups for DEVICE_ATTR
    .groups = another_attr_group,   // .groups for DRIVER_ATTR
    .release = &iio_evgen_release,
};
```

Then the attributes are automatically registered correctly without setting up anything in the probe/remove functions, as described in Greg Kroah-Hartman's article.

Assume that the module has been loaded into the kernel and the **driver** is registered in

```
/sys/bus/platform/drivers/mydrv
```

every **device** instances will be a subdirectory of the driver's folder like

```
/sys/bus/platform/drivers/mydrv/mydrv1
/sys/bus/platform/drivers/mydrv/mydrv2
```

Registering attributes in the `.groups` field creates the attributes in the **driver** folder.
Registering attributes in the `.dev_groups` field creates the attributes in the **device**'s instance folder.

```
mydrv
├── driver_attr1
├── driver_attr2
└── mydrv1
    ├── device_attr1
    └── device_attr2
```

The show/store functions of the attributes in the `.groups` field do not have access to the driver data set via `platform_set_drvdata(pdev, mydrv)`.
At least not by accessing it via `dev_get_drvdata(dev)`.
Accessing the driver data via `dev_get_drvdata(dev)` returns `NULL` and dereferencing it will result in a kernel oops.

In turn, he show/store functions of the attributes in the `.dev_groups` field have access to the driver data via

```
struct mydrv *mydrv = dev_get_drvdata(dev);
```

Comment: `struct device` doesn't have a `dev_groups` field. `struct class` and `struct bus_type` do, though.

Comment: That's right and a mistake in my answer. It should be struct device_driver instead of struct device.  struct device_driver is member of struct platform_driver.